# Exponential Families

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A family of pdfs or pmfs is called an exponential family if $$f(x|\theta) = h(x)c(\theta) \exp \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} w_{i}(\theta) t_{i}(x) \right)$$

What is the motivation of this definition? It seems that if would be easier to verify properties of pdfs such as [sufficiency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) if they are of this form? So did people come up with the definition of exponential family after Neyman and Pearson came up with the [factorization theorem](http://www.pstat.ucsb.edu/faculty/carter/classes/207/A18factorization.pdf)?

Comment: The [WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) answers thoroughly your quesyion, listing as domains of applicability of exponential families to statistics their use in classical estimation, Bayesian estimation, hypothesis testing, and generalized linear models, and explaining *why* these families are well adapted to these tasks. Which part of your question is not covered by this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Koopman-Pitman-Darmois theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Exponential_family) says that it is only for exponential families that there is a [sufficient statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) whose number of components does not grow as the size of an i.i.d. sample grows.

(But that's less than the whole story, I think.)